# Get full url path and find the string after a specific symbol

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple multilanguage, based on two buttons and get current lang by dedecting the full url path... The problem that i have with my code bellow is that it doesn't return the string after "=" equal symbol

While it display this http://www.example.com/site/?lang=en in the url, i am getting "Array"

```
<?php
$string = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$string_parts = explode("=", $string); 
if ($string_parts == "en"){
echo "English";
}

if ($string_parts == "De"){
echo "German";
}
?>
```

Comment: [`explode()` returns an array](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). You want the second element of it `$string_parts[1]`.  But _really_ what you want is `$_GET['lang']`

Comment: Yes... i TOTALY forgot it!!!! (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_GET` system array for this.

```
<?php
  $curLang = 'en'; //define a default language code

  if (isset($_GET['lang']))
  {
    $curLang = strtolower($_GET['lang']);
  }


  if ($curLang == 'de')
  {
    echo 'German';
  }
  else if ($curLang == 'fr')
  {
    echo 'French';
  }
  //... this part can be extended or converted to 'switch-case' block on demand
  else
  {
    echo 'English';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making it more complicated than it is:
`$_GET` contains all the GET-parameters passed in your url.
Try

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

to see its contents or use

```
foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v)
   echo $k.' : '.$v
```

to iterate over its content and display the key names (`$k`) and the value names (`$v`) of that array.